# A quiz web app targeted for school environment

Tags: webapp-rec

I need a suitable web app for a school environment, where:

1. A **teacher** can log in and set up a quiz (could be multiple choice or free text)
2. **Students** can log in and give their responses to the quiz
3. Web app will automatically score the quiz
4. Teacher can review the **results**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [quiz module](http://docs.moodle.org/en/Quiz_module) of [Moodle](http://moodle.org/) would meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ispringsolutions.com/ has an excellent quiz maker. It's SCORM compliant and AICC compliant, meaning it can be integrated with Moodle and various other LMS's. Alternatively, you can use it freeform to simply generate quizes and let users take them.

http://www.proprofs.com/ is another nice quiz making site and is a tad simpler than ispring. It has an excellent http://www.proprofs.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=20642 here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

1. a form builder like WUFOO
2. a quiz builder like Quibblo
3. Google Spreadsheets to create a form and have results go to a spreadsheet
4. a webapp developed for learning and quizzes such as [ProTRAX Learning System](http://www.traxintl.com/protrax-learning-system)

For quiz and learning management, I would go with a full learning management system such as ProTRAX Learning System, Moodle, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

1. [Atrixware Online Quiz Maker](http://online.quiz-maker.net/)
2. [Zoho Challenge](http://challenge.zoho.com)